# How to get the Index Name from IndexId in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm running the following query to list size and fragmentation of the indexes:

```
SELECT object_name(object_id, database_id) as objectname), index_id, *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

Is there an SQL function I can use to convert the `index_id` to the index name?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a function on [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2007/11/11/find-table-and-index-name-for-fragmented-indexes.aspx) page that should help you out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.index_name (@object_id int, @index_id int)
RETURNS sysname
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN(SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = @object_id and index_id = @index_id)
END;
```

Comment: Or, just take this logic and add it as a join to the original query

Comment: Be aware that sys.indexes is database specific. In the above question, the user shows a query to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats and specifies database_id in the OBJECT_NAME function. This function will only return results for the currently opened database.

Answer (score 9):

Or better yet:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id, d.database_id) AS objectname ,
        d.index_id ,
        i.name ,
        *
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = d.object_id
                                            AND i.index_id = d.index_id
```

Comment: tried to remove the additional parenthesis as its erroring when compiling, but cant save the edit as not 6 characters

Comment: This does not work very well as `sys.indexes` is per database view while `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` returns data for all instance databases so most `i.name` come up as NULLs.

Comment: Additionally, an index might not appear in sys.dm_db_index usage_stats because that particular system "view" is cleared each time the SQL instance/service is restarted.  An index won't show up there until it is used by by something or someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have come with this solution, works great:

```
create table dbo.IndexNames
(database_id int not null, object_id int not null, index_id int not null, index_name sysname not null)
go

create procedure dbo.GatherIndexNames
as
begin    
declare @cur cursor
,@name varchar(128)
,@sql varchar(max)

truncate table dbo.IndexNames

set @cur = cursor for select name from sys.databases
    where database_id >= 5

open @cur
fetch next from @cur into @name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql = '
    insert into dbo.IndexNames 
    (database_id, object_id, index_id, index_name)
        select db_id(''' + @name + '''),t.object_id, i.index_id, i.name
        from [' + @name + '].[sys].[tables] t
        inner join [' + @name + '].[sys].[indexes] i 
        on t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
        where i.index_id <> 0'
    exec (@sql)

    fetch next from @cur into @name   
end
```